# How to access member variable using accessor which name is being passed in variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a list of instances of a class and I have a hash with changes I’d like to apply to these instances. I can’t figure how to access member variable which name I have in list of changes.

E.g.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor: foo
  def initialize value
    @foo = value
  end
end

f = Foo.new("bar")
```

I can obviously access `@foo` with `f.foo`, but say I have list of changes in form like `changes = {"foo" => "baz"}`.

Now I wonder wheter there is a way to do something like this:

```
changes.each do |k,v|
  f.k = v
end
```

to have `f.foo` changed to `"baz"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send` method can help you assign attributes dynamically.

```
changes.each do |k,v|
  f.send("#{k}=", v)
end
```